# Android app seems hanging

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to move from one activity to another activity. But some times seems it is hanging. On screen off and On it is working fine. 
eg: 
I am in **Activity 1**
Moved from **Activity 1** to **Activity 2**
Seems it is hanged.
But if I do screen off and on it is on **Activity 1**.

Below is my Code sample:

```
Intent i;
 i = new Intent(AdvSeatAvail.this, TrainsBetweenTwoStationsList.class);
 i.putExtra("anim id in", R.anim.fragment_slide_right_enter);
 i.putExtra("anim id out", R.anim.fragment_slide_left_exit);
 i.putExtra("jsonvalue", jsonvalue);
 i.putExtra("dateval", dateval);

 AdvSeatAvail.this.finish();
 AdvSeatAvail.this.startActivity(i);
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fragment_slide_right_enter,  R.anim.fragment_slide_left_exit);
```

Some one please help me to resolve this Issue.

--
thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below lines of code for it..
Firstly call another activity than finish the class

```
Intent i;
i = new Intent(AdvSeatAvail.this, TrainsBetweenTwoStationsList.class);
i.putExtra("anim id in", R.anim.fragment_slide_right_enter);
i.putExtra("anim id out", R.anim.fragment_slide_left_exit);
i.putExtra("jsonvalue", jsonvalue);
i.putExtra("dateval", dateval);

AdvSeatAvail.this.startActivity(i); //// FIRTLY START THE CLASS AND THAN FINISH THE CLASS

AdvSeatAvail.this.finish();

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fragment_slide_right_enter,     R.anim.fragment_slide_left_exit);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution Still it is hanging some times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    finish();
    Intent i = new Intent(AdvSeatAvail.this, TrainsBetweenTwoStationsList.class);
    /* putExtra stuff */
    startActivity(i);
```

Hopefuly it will help.

Comment: what is the difference between using of startActivity(i); and AdvSeatAvail.this.startActivity(i);